# filter children in self refernce entity

Tags: entity-framework

I have this model for comment that each comment can be the answer of an other comment.

```
 public class Comment
 {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Body { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? AddedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsApproved { get; set; }
    public virtual int LikeCount { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual AnonymousUser AnonymousUser { get; set; }
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
    public virtual Page Page { get; set; }
    public virtual int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Comment Parent { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Children { get; set; }
    public virtual byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
 }
```

I try this code to fetch comments that "IsApproved==true"

```
this._comments
            .Where(comment => comment.Post.Id == postId).Include(comment => comment.User)
            .Include(comment => comment.AnonymousUser)
            .Include(comment => comment.Children).Where(comment => comment.IsApproved == true)
            .OrderBy(comment => comment.AddedDate)
            .Skip(page * count)
            .Take(count).ToList()
            .Where(comment => comment.Parent == null).ToList();
```

But this query returns just the **root** comments that "IsApproved==true".

What shoud i do to filter all the comments even children.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will return only root comment because of `.Where(comment => comment.Parent == null)`.

But in general...

If i understood you correctly you want to get all the comments (including child comments) in flat list that are approved and are under specific post, am I right ?

Assumptions : 
Each comment has post populated - even children.

```
this._comments
        .Include(comment => comment.User)
        .Include(comment => comment.AnnonymousUser)
        .Include(comment => comment.Children)
        .Where(comment => comment.IsApproved && comment.Post.Id == postId)
        .OrderBy(comment => comment.AddedDate)
        .Skip(page * count)
        .Take(count)
        .ToList();
```

Edit:

Or if you just want to filter children for the ones that have been approved look at this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx, section **Applying filters when explicitly loading related entities**

Comment: ".Where(comment => comment.Parent == null" is for treeview heper.

Comment: So I'm a bit confused about what you want to achieve? Do you want to get all comments that have been approved with only children that have been approved as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Try Any when filtering through children.

```
this._comments
            .Where(comment => comment.Post.Id == postId).Include(comment => comment.User)
            .Include(comment => comment.AnnonymousUser)
            .Where(comment => comment.Children.Any(child=>child.IsApproved == true))
            .OrderBy(comment => comment.AddedDate)
            .Skip(page * count)
            .Take(count).ToList()
            .Where(comment => comment.Parent == null).ToList();
```

Comment: I probably misunderstood what do you want exaclty.